# JobScheduler API crash on Android 8.0 devices

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-jobscheduler, android-8.1-oreo

In order to meet Android target API 26 requirements for my app, I modified the background service in my app to be launched with a JobScheduler instead of just as a plain service. Here is my updated code.

**In my PhoneUtils class,**

```
 public static void scheduleTTSJob(Context context) {

    if(isTTSJobServiceOn(context))
    {
        return;
    }

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        ComponentName serviceComponent = new ComponentName(context, TTSJobScheduledService.class);
        JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(JOB_ID, serviceComponent);

        builder.setMinimumLatency(1 * 1000); // wait at least
        builder.setOverrideDeadline(3 * 1000); // maximum delay
        JobScheduler jobScheduler = context.getSystemService(JobScheduler.class);
        jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
    }
}

public static boolean isTTSJobServiceOn( Context context ) {

    boolean hasBeenScheduled = false;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService( Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE );

        for ( JobInfo jobInfo : scheduler.getAllPendingJobs() ) {
            if ( jobInfo.getId() == JOB_ID ) {
                hasBeenScheduled = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return hasBeenScheduled;
}

public static void stopTTSJob(Context context)
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService( Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE );

        for ( JobInfo jobInfo : scheduler.getAllPendingJobs() ) {
            if ( jobInfo.getId() == JOB_ID ) {

                scheduler.cancel(JOB_ID);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**TTSJobScheduledService class**

```
package services;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.job.JobParameters;
import android.app.job.JobService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;

import utilities.PhoneUtils;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public class TTSJobScheduledService extends JobService {

@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
    Intent service = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TTSService.class);
    getApplicationContext().startService(service);
    PhoneUtils.scheduleTTSJob(getApplicationContext()); // reschedule the job
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
    return true;
    }
}
```

**Code for TTSService class:**

```
package services;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

public class TTSService extends Service {

   private static TextToSpeech voice =null;

   public static TextToSpeech getVoice() {
    return voice;
}

@Nullable
@Override

public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // not supporting binding
    return null;
}

public TTSService() {
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    try{

            voice = new TextToSpeech(TTSService.this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInit(final int status) {

                }
            });
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    clearTtsEngine();
    super.onDestroy();

}

public static void clearTtsEngine()
{
    if(voice!=null)
    {
        voice.stop();
        voice.shutdown();
        voice = null;
    }
}
}
```

Also, I added this new service in my manifest file:

```
<service
        android:name="services.TTSJobScheduledService"
        android:label="TTS service"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" >

</service>
```

I am scheduling this service when user opens my app (if it is not already scheduled), or if device is rebooted, or if app is upgraded on Google Play.

However, soon after I released this app update, I started getting crashes with this stack trace for devices with Android 8.0.0 and above:

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=abc.fgh.com.abc/services.TTSService }: app is in background uid UidRecord{6dafcbe u0a250 TRNB idle procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
   at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1505)
   at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1461)
   at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:644)
   at services.TTSJobScheduledService.onStartJob(Unknown Source:15)
   at android.app.job.JobService$1.onStartJob(JobService.java:71)
   at android.app.job.JobServiceEngine$JobHandler.handleMessage(JobServiceEngine.java:108)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:180)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6950)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:835)
```

As I understand, this should not be happening given that I am using a JobScheduledService scheduleTTSJob() call and not a plain startService() call from my code. It did not crash on device I tested it on (Moto G6), which is also having Android 8.0.0, but is now crashing on these other devices with Android 8.0.0 and above.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Didn't know this was a thing. Sorry about that, will keep this in mind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As I understand, this should not be happening given that I am using a JobScHeduledService scheduleTTSJob() call and not a plain startService() call from my code

You are definitely using a plain `startService()` call from your code. It is in your `onStartJob()` method:

```
@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
    Intent service = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TTSService.class);
    getApplicationContext().startService(service);
    PhoneUtils.scheduleTTSJob(getApplicationContext()); // reschedule the job
    return true;
}
```

and that is where the stack trace shows that you are crashing.

> Please let me know what is the fix to be made in my code

Either:

- Delete that `startService()` call, or
- Use `ContextCompat.startForegroundService()` and have `TTSService` call `startForeground()` as it starts up, or
- If applicable, move that `TTSService` logic into some non-service code in a background thread that you execute directly from `onStartJob()`

It is difficult to give you more specific advice, given that we do not know what `TTSService` is.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply :) I tried using startForegroundService(), but it results in a permanent notification on my device status bar saying "ABC app is running", when ABC is my app. This did not go well with some of my users, which is why I wanted to resort to this. Basically my TTSService starts up a TTS object which is used to output some speech, when my app instance may or may not be active. How do I avoid this in that case?

Comment: I have updated the code for TTSService class. Please advise.

Comment: @SoulRayder: `JobScheduler` is for work to be done at a semi-random time in the future, so I'm not really sure how it would fit into a TTS scenario. But assuming that a semi-random time is fine, then do your TTS work from your `JobService`. Kick off a background thread from `onStartJob()` that does your TTS-ing.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. Will try that :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know how it still worked on my test device Moto G6, which is also on Android 8.0.0, without crashing even once? Since it worked fine on this device, I assumed it would work fine on all other devices with Oreo and above

Comment: @SoulRayder: I have no idea, sorry. I would expect your `startService()` to crash on all Android 8.0+ devices.